# How many squares can you make with equal ranged points?

Tags: logical-deduction, combinatorics

This question is directly related to [How Many Squares on the Peg Solitaire](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51773/how-many-squares-on-the-peg-solitaire).

Is it possible to formulate with a given dimension of equal ranged points $m\times n$ where $m,n\geqslant 2$?

For example;

> $2\times2$ there is only $1$ square possible:

[image]

> $3\times2$ there are only $2$ squares possible and $3\times3$ there are $6$ squares shown as below:

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Looks like something that's polynomial in two variables - if so, plugging in lots of small m and n would give you the answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the general case, let's assume that 2 ≤ *n* ≤ *m*.

Every possible square has an axis-aligned boundary box that is a square of edge length *a*. Such a square can fit into the *n* × *m* grid at

*P*(*a*) = (*m* − *a*) (*n* − *a*)

positions, see illustration below (left). If we define each square by the edge of its north-west corner (*dx*, *dy*), *dx* > 0, *dy* ≥ 0; the edge length of the bounding box is

*a* = *dx* + *dy* .

There are *a* possibilities to split each *a* into *dx* and *dy* as shown below (right). (Note that *dx* can't be zero, because such a square would be a 90° rotation of an axis-aligned square that has already been accounted for by the case where *dy*  is zero.)

[image: possible bounding-box positions and possible squares in bounding box]

Possible edge lengths of bounding boxes are 0 < *a* < *n*. Therefore, the number of squares that fit into a grid of *n* × *m* nodes is:

*N* = ∑<sub>*a*</sub> *a* · (*m* − *a*) (*n* − *a*);    *a* = 1,..., *n* − 1
   = ∑<sub>*a*</sub> (*a*³ − (*m* + *n*) *a*² + *m* *n* *a*)

Using the well-known (i.e. easily googleable) [Faulhaber formulas](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/), we get:

*N*= ¹/₄ (*n* − 1)² *n*²
                − ¹/₆ (n − 1) (n (2n − 1) (*m* + *n*)
                 + ¹/₂ (*n* − 1) *n*² *m*

and after a bit of rearranging and simplifying:

*N*(*n*, *m*) = ¹/₁₂ (*n* − 1) *n* (*n* + 1) (2 *m* − *n*)

My approach is different from (and perhaps less elegant than) Wen1now's, but it arrives at the same solution. There's a difference in nomenclature; *k* is the edge length of the grid, *m* and *n* are the numbers of pegs along the edge as in the question. If we set *n* = *m* = *k* + 1, we get:

*N*(*k*) = ¹/₁₂ *k* (*k* + 1)² (*k* + 2)

Comment: So what is the formula which is symmetric in `n` and `m` (recall that you assumed `n<=m`)?

Comment: I assumed _n_ ≤ _m_ so that I didn't have to use min(_n_, _m_) when I determine the number of square positions and the upper bound for the sums. I don't know whether there really is a symmatric formula.

Comment: In  “k is the edgel length of the grid, m and n are the numbers of pegs along the adge” are edgel and adge technical terms, or typos?

Comment: No, they are typos, of course. It should be "edge" in both cases. As I get older, I get sloppier and sloppier at typing and it bugs me.

Comment: Nice! This formula in m and n is really nice as well.

Comment: @MOehm if you fix the N(n,m) equation, I will accept your answer, check that out again! (2m-1) or (2m-n)? :)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm pretty sure that this happend when typing in the answer, but I can't tell for sure now: I'm at the office now and my notes are at home.

Answer (score 15):

**I will deal with the $n\times n$ case only**

Summarising [this](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/squares-on-a-grid/) :)

Let $T_n$ be the total number of squares (including tilted ones) on a square grid and let $N_n$ be the number of 'normal' squares, oriented such that the sides of these squares are parallel to the sides of the original grid. I claim that $T_n=T_{n-1}+N_n$ by providing a bijection between tilted squares in a $n\times n$ grid and all squares in a $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ grid. For any square in a $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ grid, fix the top right corner (top takes priority - so a diagonal square would just be the top corner) and move the vertex that is **counterclockwise** around from it down one unit. Then this forms a side of a new square (such that the top right vertex is still the top right vertex). This is non-trivially a bijection, but it is not that hard to prove either so I leave it as an exercise.

Bijection picture (appropriated from brilliant.org): [image]

So since $N_n = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ (which can be found just about [anywhere](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=number+of+squares+in+a+rectangular+grid&oq=number+of+squares+in+a+rectangular+grid&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59.4974j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=number+of+squares+in+a+square+grid)) we can sum the first $n$ things to find $T_n$. This turns out to be

$\frac{n(n+1)^2(n+2)}{12}$

I believe. We could check - base case n=1 both sides are equal.

Assume that it is equal for $n$. Then increasing by 1 gives

$\frac{n(n+1)^2(n+2)}{12} + \frac{2(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{12}$, which, after some algebraic manipulation should yield $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)^2(n+3)}{12}$ which is what we wanted.

So the number of squares on a $n\times n$ grid is a neat

$\frac{n(n+1)^2(n+2)}{12} \square$

Mathematics can be so beautiful.