# Total no of squares on a Chess Board

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, checkerboard

Is there any formula than calculates the total number of squares on chessboard?

For example in a $8\times8$ chessboard, there are squares of sizes $1\times1$, $2\times2$, $\ldots$, $8\times8$.

So I want to know their total number. Is there a general formula for a $n\times n$ chessboard?

Comment: Yes, it's classroom assignment question but not sure both have same assignment..

Comment: Yes the logic is same, but only the representation is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are

> $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 + 8^2 = 204$ squares on an $8\times8$ board.
>  In the general case, the number of squares is  $1^2 + \dots + n^2$ for an $n\times n$ board,
>  or equivalently,  $\rlap{\raise{2.5ex}{~\scriptsize ~n}}{\rlap{\lower{2ex}{\scriptsize{k\text{=1}}}}{\large{\sum}~k^2}}$.
>  As **[@M Oehm noted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52500/30633)**, a **[Faulhaber formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/)** lets us simplify this to  $\large ~~\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$.

This is because ...

> For $1\times1$ squares, there are obviously $n^2$ of them.
>  You can fit $(n-1)$ rows of $2\times2$ squares in an $n^2$ area, and each row has $(n-1)$ in it.
>  You can fit $(n-2)$ rows of $3\times3$ squares in an $n^2$ area, and each row has $(n-2)$ in it.
>  ...
>  You can fit $2$ rows of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ squares in an $n^2$ area, and each row has $2$ in it.
>  And finally, of course, you can fit 1 $(n\times n)$ square in an $n^2$ area.
>  This expands to
>  $n^2 + (n-1)^2 + \dots + 2^2 + 1^2 = \rlap{\raise{2.5ex}{~\scriptsize ~n}}{\rlap{\lower{2ex}{\scriptsize{k\text{=1}}}}{\large{\sum}~k^2}} = \large ~~\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that it's equal to $\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?

Comment: Took a while to get a $\sum$ formula to look right inside a spoiler - finally sussed it out.

Answer (score 6):

In an *n* × *n* checkerboard, there are:

- *n*² squares of edge length 1;
- (*n* − 1)² squares of edge length 2;
- (*n* − 2)² squares of edge length 3;
- ...
- 9 squares of edge length *n* − 2
- 4 squares of edge length *n* − 1
- 1 square of edge length *n*

In other words, there are

∑ *k*²;   *k* = 1, ..., *n*

squares. With the [Faulhaber formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/), you can simplify this to:

¹/₆ *n* · (*n* + 1) · (2 *n* + 1)

On the regular checker board, where *n* = 8, there are 204 squares.

**Caveat**: This formula counts only the axis-aligned squares. If squares can be drawn with any grid point between the cells as corner, the solution is [different](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51814/how-many-squares-can-you-make-with-equal-ranged-points/51819).

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at the patterns:

---

There is $1$ square in a $1$x$1$ square.

There is $5$ squares in a $2$x$2$ square, 4 small, 1 large.

There is $14$ squares in a $3$x$3$ square, 9 small, 4 medium, 1 large

There is $30$ squares in a $4$x$4$ square, 16 small, 9 medium, 4 large, 1 extra large.

---

Notice anything? These are [the square pyramidal numbers according to oeis](https://oeis.org/A000330) and [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)

> 'Square pyramidal numbers also solve the problem of counting the number of squares in an n × n grid.'

For an $n$x$n$ box, it is the sum of $n^2 + (n-1)^2 + (n-2)^2 + ... + 0^2$, or more simply the sum of $n^2$ and all previous squares

From this we can derive the final formula for the total amounts of squares, $t$ in an $n$x$n$ grid:

> $$t=\frac{n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)}{6}$$

Comment: I'll add a few diagrams for how many squares in a $n$x$n$ grid, otherwise theres no proof

Comment: That formula isn't the same thing. For instance, for $n=2$ it gives 6 squares rather than 5.

Comment: @Deusovi oops. I just found a better one anyway, editing...

Comment: It should be $(n-1)*(n-1)$, not $n(n-1)$

Comment: @Beastly: Perfect, appreciated your help. This will not calculate rectangles, only squares, right..?

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya yes only squares. (Also see updated formula, previous was incorrect) A rectangular grid would be $n$x$m$ which would be very different

Comment: @Narusan thanks, removed it all together. Theres a better formula on oeis

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya updated to link the wiki page, it is very informative